# JS - Show highest score and name associated with that score

Tags: javascript, arrays

[High score fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J45xQ/3/)

JS code:

```
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];
var textDisplay;

var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};


var listArray = function () {
    var scoresString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        scoresString += names[i] + ", " + scores[i] + "\n";
    } // lists all names and scores in their respective array orders
    $("results").value = scoresString;

};

var showBest = function () {
    var bestString = "";
    var highScore = Math.max.apply(Math, scores);
    for (var i in scores) {
        if (scores[i] > highScore) highScore = scores[i];
        bestString += "High Score Student = " + names[i] + "\n" + "High Score = " + highScore;
    }
    $("results").value = bestString;
};

    $("add").onclick = addElement;
    $("name").focus();
    $("list_array").onclick = listArray;
    $("show_best").onclick = showBest;
```

"Show Best Score" button should show the highest scoring student name along with their score. Right now, it shows the highest score, but it also associates that score with all the names in the array so all the names show up with the same high score. I only want the name associated with the highest score (1 name, 1 score).

Any input would be much appreciated!

Edit: My question is for var showBest - how do I get just one name and one score to show? Right now it shows all name and one high score.

Comment: You haven't asked a clear question. Is there something wrong with your code? Were you expecting people to read through your code and figure out what you want done?

Comment: Sorry @NateC-K it was a statement in my original. Added the question now :)

Comment: why are they separate arrays? why not a collection that associates the score to the user? otherwise how is one to know which score belongs to which user?

Comment: @ChaseFlorell the arrays are separate in the original code from my textbook. This is for an intro JS course.

Comment: Then your code is going to need to combine it for you. `var users = [
    {"name": "joe", "score": 89},
    {"name": "john", "score": 128}
];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track:

```
var highScore = Math.max.apply(Math, scores);     // gives the highest score
var scoreIndex = scores.indexOf(highScore);       // gives the location of the highest score
var bestStudent = names[scoreIndex];              // gets the name at the same location
var bestString += "High Score Student = " + bestStudent + "\n" + "High Score = " + highScore;
```

this code is assuming that the 2 arrays are in the appropriate order.

Comment: Ok, so I changed that part of it but now the button doesn't work. I'm not sure if I did anything wrong: [update] (http://jsfiddle.net/J45xQ/6/)

Comment: If you use the browser's developer tools (in Chrome or IE, press F12) you'll see the error when you click the button. Looks like you've spelled `indexOf` with a capital `I`

Comment: Sorry, I've done the same in my code sample. Updated

Comment: Ahh, I thought it was weird that it wasn't camel cased haha. Thanks so much!